# Install Mono Runtime Locally

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Here is my situation. I am on a Mac using Brew as my package manager. I had mono installed on my machine and I was doing all sorts of development in C#. I was doing web development, gui development, ect. When I tried to update my machine using Brew, I got an error. Uninstalling Mono solved the issue.

So, what I did is I toyed around and I created a 2nd user on my machine. Now, this user doesn't need anything to work. I just need Mono and Mono Develop to work on this user without installing anything globally. Everything needs to be installed locally.

So to be specific, I am the only on who uses my machine. My /Users directory looks like this.

```
/Users/dillon
/Users/dummy
```

So if I could install mono, in let's say:

```
/Users/dummy/.mono
```

Then in my .profile:

```
export MONO_PATH=/Users/dummy/.mono
```

Obviously this isn't a perfect world but I was wondering if anyone is an expert on this subject?
(Also, I use this dummy user for other stuff, I use it for Wine and I have a collection of software from school on this user.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build Mono from source to install it into a custom location (in which case you can install it anywhere you like).

You can install MonoDevelop.app anywhere, but getting it to use your custom Mono is a bit trickier. You might be able to make it work by mucking around with the relevant environment variables though.

How to install Mono in a custom location and the relevant environment variables is all covered here: http://mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Comment: Ya I was on that link and it is a bit outdated (the download links give 404s). It's also relevant to GNOME, its a bit trickier in my situation. I'll get back to you after toying around some more.

Comment: Okay I have a question, this is kind of unrelated/amateur. I need to log into root to install mono. If I install this as root using ./configure --PREFIX=/Users/dummy/.mono then I get mono running locally on dummy?

Comment: You shouldn't need to log in as root to install into /Users/dummy

Comment: Your `MonoDevelop.app` won't use a custom mono, the paths to the runtime are hardcoded in its launcher script.  And running `mono MonoDevelop.exe` is more than tricky.  I had this working once after many hours of experimenting, but unfortunately forgot which environment variables I was using.

For testing, you can simply load `main/Main.sln` in MonoDevelop, select your target runtime, compile and run.

Comment: If someone wants to do some research here, last time I got this working, I set a breakpoint in `MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main`, dumped all environment variables then set exactly these variables on the command line.

To run `MonoDevelop.app` with another runtime, you need to edit `main/build/MacOSX/monostub.m` and change the paths in there.

Comment: I made a [blog post](http://baulig.blogspot.de/2012/12/running-monomac-application-with-custom.html) which explains how to run MonoDevelop with a custom Mono runtime.